# Codeigniter Activerecord update method refuses to insert NULL value

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm using Codeigniters Active record library to carry out an update on a column on my DB.

Here's the SQL for the table

```
CREATE TABLE `schedules` (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`reservation_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`description` VARCHAR(512) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`start_date` DATE NOT NULL,
`start_time` TIME NOT NULL,
`end_time` TIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`enabled` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT '1',
`status` ENUM('OPEN','RESERVED') NULL DEFAULT 'OPEN',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
INDEX `fk_schedules_reservations` (`reservation_id`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_schedules_reservations` FOREIGN KEY (`reservation_id`) REFERENCES `reservations` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
```

)

I've declared reservation_id as nullable (`reservation_id INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL`)

The problem is that CI doesn't seem to want to send a NULL value when I create the statement.

```
$data['status'] = $this->Schedule->get_status_open();
$data['reservation_id'] = null; 
$this->Schedule->update($s_id, $data);
```

That bit of code just generates the following error message

```
Error Number: 1452

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ethyme/schedules`, CONSTRAINT `fk_schedules_reservations` FOREIGN KEY (`reservation_id`) REFERENCES `reservations` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

UPDATE `schedules` SET `status` = 'OPEN', `reservation_id` = '' WHERE `id` = '4'
```

From what I know, all you have to do is set the value to NULL and AR should pick up that it's a NULL value, but that doesn't seem to be the case here. Just keeps sending empty values.

I'm new to CI, do I have to do anything else to make it work? any ideas?

Comment: This turned out to be a non issue. The base model I was using was using xss_clean to filter data, and it was garbling up data types like NULL, TRUE, FALSE and so forth. Adding an exclusion list solved the problem. The above is the CORRECT way to send NULL data

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try:

```
$this->db->set('reservation_id', NULL);
```

Could well be the $data approach doesn't like NULLs.

Comment: excellent! that worked. Sadly this means I won't be able to use the $data approach unless I work in an intermediary method that iterates through the array and sets the data. Anyway, problem solved. Thanks for your help everyone

Comment: did a bit more digging, turns out xss_clean was munching up my data. Added an exclusion list for data types so it would ignore NULL, TRUE, FALSE. Looks like the usage was correct after all :/

Comment: Yeah I figured it might be a bug, but I knew that way to work. Can you submit the bug to the CodeIgniter Issue Tracker on BitBucket and I'll try to get a fix into the core. Also, you can mix $data and ->set() as much as you like.

Comment: @JohnP how did you add the exclusion list?

Comment: @Jonah I just modified the validate() method in my base model. This would apply only if you're using the same base model though

Answer (score 2):

I handled it this way: extend the CI_Model class with this method to handle nulls.  You have to call it each time you expect a null though.  I don't use nulls that often, so this method is fine for when I need to set null.  Just pass a string 'NULL' from the data array.  This unsets the array member and sets it into the active record cache.

```
     class MY_Model extends CI_Model {

      public function __construct() {
          parent::__construct();
      }

      /* Handles null values for active record data array.  If 
       * $dataarray[$data_key] is string 'NULL',
       * use active record set method to set null and unset the 
       * string 'NULL'.  $data_array is by reference.
       * @param - array   the data array
       * @param - data_key - string  the key to be evaluated */
      protected function handle_null_active_record(&$data_array, $data_key){
        if ('NULL'==$data_array[$data_key]){
          $this->db->set($data_key, null);
          unset($data_array[$data_key]);
        }
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In CI the keyword NULL always needs to be uppercase. Try this simple change and see if that works.
See the relevant bit of the userguide [here.](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html)

Comment: nope, I had tried that earlier as well, still won't work. Since it's a null datatype, I don't think the case would have made much difference anyway.

Comment: That is part of the style guide and makes no difference to anything whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Your reservations_id column references an id column in a reservations table, right? Have you checked that the column in the reservstions table is also allowed to have a null value? If its the primary key and auto-incremented then that could well be the problem. I dont think you can have a column as null in one table if its designated as a foreign key to a column that cant be null in the referenced table. 
Have i explained that clearly for you?

Comment: That's not the problem because I ran the query manually with null instead of quotes and it worked fine. I just need to actually be able to send the null value instead of the blank. Short of turning this into a custom query, nothing comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

From CI 3.0.0's documentation:

**set()** will also accept an optional third parameter ($escape), that will prevent data from being escaped if set to **false**.

```
$this->db->set('reservation_id', 'NULL', false);
```